# Is "…süchtig" temporary or lasting?

Tags: meaning, single-word-request, adjective

There's a lot of "…süchtig"-words, e.g. "spielsüchtig", "eifersüchtig", "morphiumsüchtig", "abenteuersüchtig" and "internetsüchtig".

Do these words convey temporary desire — the wish to have an adventure or a morphine fix right now — or the more permanent state — the drug addiction or the personality trait of seeking adventures?

If the answer is only one of the meanings: Is there a similar word for the other meaning?

Comment: Please note that "eifersüchtig" does not follow this pattern, it has a different meaning and means "jealous" and is not an "addiction" in the conventional sense.

Comment: @phant0m: Is it still a lasting state? "Er ist ein eifersüchtiger Mensch" as opposed to "heute ist er eifersüchtig".

Comment: I would not ever say "Heute ist er eifersüchtig", because you don't just "decide" to be jealous, you're jealous of somebody, perhaps because he bought something you don't have. In that case, it is temporary of course. I think it's a question of character whether somebody is getting jealous easily. I would argue, though not being a native speaker, that the usage is virtually the same as in english.

Comment: For what it's worth, `Wahrig` says (among other things): `eifersüchtig: Eifersucht empfindend` Eifersucht: *1* leidenschatl. Streben nach Alleinbesitz, Geltung u.Ä. *2* Angst vor Nebenbuhlern od. Zurücksetzung [...] (**eigtl. "Krankheit des Eiferns"**)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By using the suffix *"-süchtig"* we express a person's obsession or addiction (in the meaning of *"Sucht"*) as well as an exceeding propensity towards something. This is generally not temporary as it describes a lasting attitude or character of a person.

For a more short term desire we can sometimes use the suffix *"-lustig"* (in the meaning of *"Lust"*). However in the examples given this only works with *"abenteuerlustig"*. In addition, there are combinations such as *"aggressionslustig"* where the temporary nature also is questionable.

In contemporary colloquial or slang German the suffix *"-geil"* is used to describe a more temporary state (e.g. *"sensationsgeil"*, *"karrieregeil"*, *"affengeil"*).

Another more short-lasting suffix that comes to mind in *"-hungrig"*.

Comment: A better word for "aggressionslustig" might be "angriffslustig".